# PHPExcel - Templates work but mine are corrupt

Tags: php, phpexcel

I am trying to write data to a template and download it.
If i use the sample files as a template, it works but once I use my own it says its corrupt.

Any thoughts?

My code is:

```
<?php
require_once 'PHPExcel.php';

// Create new PHPExcel object
$fileName = '31docproperties.xlsx'; //location of template for PID type
$fileType = 'Excel2007';
$objReader = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader($fileType);
$objPHPExcel = $objReader->load($fileName);

$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)->setCellValue('B4', 'Test Data');


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel2007)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xlsx"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
ob_end_clean();
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel2007');
$objWriter->save('php://output');
exit;
?>
```

Comment: What format is your own template? What might be in that template that PHPExcel can't handle (e.g. pivot tables, macros)?

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry for the late reply - no, nothing like that. It has a few simple formulae (=C4 etc) so nothing taxing. The formatting is also nothing special either.

Comment: It's possible that there is a bug in PHPExcel, but unless you can isolate the problem there's very little I can do to help.... there's something in your template that PHPExcel doesn't like, but I can't even begin to guess what it might be

Comment: @MarkBaker I've managed to find the template and upload it to DropBox. Do you have a list of what is currently not supported by PHPExel?

[link](https://www.dropbox.com/s/o22f2bunlyx8srg/TEMPLATE.xlsx)

Comment: @MarkBaker Sorry to pester - I know you're busy. But have you had a chance to look at this? The link to my template is at the very end of my previous comment. Thanks.